# Continuity at a single point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb R$. Find a function $f$ such that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and not continuous at any other point.

So I was thinking for this problem that if I let $p(x)$ be some polynomial that has roots exactly at $x = a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ such as $p(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)\ldots(x-a_n)$ and then define some function $f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} p(x) & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

Any input/direction on my thinking, correct or incorrect, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, your construction is correct. (Are you able to prove it, though?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard answer is 
$$
f(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
x-a & x \mbox{ irrational} \\
0 & \mbox{ rational}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: What type of clarification, if any, would I need if I went with this function?  Your function makes a lot more sense to me, but I most likely need some sort of clarifying statements to go along with it.  I was thinking I can say because there is never a number in between x-a, because it is irrational, that it is only continuous at that point, while if x-a were rational, there would be some irrational point in x-a, which would make the function continuous at more than one point?

Answer (score 0):

Is correct, note that if you're near a root, then because of continuity of the polynomial, given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some ball $B_{\delta}(a_1)$ such that $p(B_{\delta}(a_1)) \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(p(a_1)) = B_{\varepsilon}(0)$, in particular $|x-a| < \varepsilon$, now it should be obvious that using that $\delta$, given $x \in B_{\delta}(a_1)$ if $x$ is irrational, $|x-a| \leq \varepsilon$ and if its rational $0 < \varepsilon$. So $f(x)$ is continuous at $a_1$. Rinse and repeat for the other roots.